# How to pass custom yaml file to helm without mentioning its name

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am new to helm chart. As part of the requirement I named my *values.yaml* to *customize.yaml* 
To tell helm engine that I am using custom yaml file, I used the below command.
 `helm install mychart -f customize.yaml` 

but now the question is how should I not pass the name of the yaml *(customize.yaml)* file as part of the command, so the command should be like this
 
 `helm install mychart` 

and helm should know that it will get the values from *customize.yaml*
without explicitly mentioning it in the command. Is there a way to do this?

I tried to include it in  _helpers.tpl but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
// ValuesfileName is the default values file name.
ValuesfileName = "values.yaml"
```

values.yaml have been defined as the default file in helm's source code. So, in your case, you may have to build helm from source with your changes.

Comment: Thanks @hariK. Can you please let know where this "ValuesfileName" is mentioned in helm ?

Comment: I am able to find it in helm/pkg/chartutil/create.go but I want to do it configurationally. Is there any configuration settings that I can do so that my  customize.yaml becomes the default yaml.

Comment: You need to use the `helm install -f` command-line option to tell Helm about the additional file.  I'm not sure what sort of configuration you're looking for, if not that.